# Most Appropriate Way To Implement Complex Configuration Data?

Tags: entities

I need to create admin for content that makes a series of nested references to our separate data API. When a new content-item is created, the user selects one or more data sources from a (large) list. Then they create a list of one or more references to those selected sources. For each reference, they choose from a list of items available for that source. For each of *those* datasource-item's, they enter a few text fields and zero or more references to attributes available for that datasource. And for those attribute references, they can select one or more from a list of possible values.

The exact structure of this item changes with the project and my knowledge of the Field & Form APIs isn't great. So I have built this functionality with JavascriptMVC and have been serializing JSON into a bare bones Drupal text field.

AJAX forms in D7 seem amenable to building out the form itself, but what should I do with the values? Should I implement content types A, B and C and hook everything together with nodereference fields? That seems heavy and cumbersome to change as the project evolves. I don't know if Entity would be more appropriate or maybe something I'm not aware of.

Comment: Yes, Entity definitely seems to be your dog here, with some of its fellow companion modules. [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) in particular could be most useful to you.

Comment: What are the advantages over simply serializing JSON to  a simple DB text field?

Comment: Well, as usual with Drupal or any other OS project : why using it if you don't leverage the functionality it's giving ? And a better level of abstraction, heavy tested comunity code, reliable API and so on ...

Comment: Thanks, Countzero. The sub-types won't ever need to be listed apart from their parent instance and I'm seeing there might still be benefit in creating entities for them -- just without the ability to list them. Is there an example or do you have thoughts on how to build the nested forms with dynamic sub-options based on parents' selections from the separate Data API?

Comment: Re-reading your descrption more carefully, it's possible you can manage your implementation with [states](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7). You can switch on or off any element based on any conditions. That way you can use what you've already done to your heart's content, and benefit from the very powerful FAPI.

Comment: I've been working on the entity implementation. What is available to implement the nested entity form situation? Form collection would seem to be the way except for the references I need to make up and down the hierarchy. I have EntityA that has one or more EntityB's that each have one or more EntityC's. I'm looking at building the lists from Subform (http://drupal.org/project/subform) but it seems this would have been solved already.

Comment: I can't be of much help. Your problem seems very specific, and short of what I've already told, I have no more ideas to share.